# Ruby class naming convention with double colon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know the `::` in Ruby is a scope resolution operator to access methods within modules and classes, but is it proper to name classes using `::`?

Example

```
class Foo::Bar::Bee < Foo::Bar::Insect

  def a_method
    [...]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5):

If by “proper” you mean syntactically correct — **yes**.

There's nothing inherently wrong with doing it, and if you're defining a subclass in a separate file (example below) then it's a relatively common practice.

```
# lib/foo.rb
module Foo
end

# lib/foo/bar.rb
class Foo::Bar
end
```

I would avoid defining classes this way if you cannot be sure that the parent module or class already exists, though, as you'll get a `NameError` due to the parent (e.g. `Foo`) not existing. For this reason, you won't see much open source software that follows the more terse pattern.

#### In isolation, this will not work:

```
class Foo::Bar
end
```

#### This, however, would work:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Comment: What if the second constant in that name does not correlate to any sub module or class? For example the inherited class `Foo::Bar::Insect` Bar is not actually a sub module or class?

Comment: To be clear, I don't mean an inherited subclass, I mean a namespaced class or module, in which case it isn't `Foo::Bar`, it's just `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

The usage is perfectly valid.

Just be wary of the gotcha:

```
class Foo::Bar; end   #  uninitialized constant Foo (NameError)
```

This will work fine:

```
module Foo; end
class Foo::Bar; end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that usage is perfectly valid. The format is simply a way to reference the constant; the expression resolves to a single constant all the same.